# Without rowkey in csv file can we upload bulk data into Hbase file using command line or any other way?

Tags: csv, hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, apache-phoenix

I have 1 corer records of `csv` file but not having `rowkey` or auto-increment id and I want to upload that file into `hbase` table. But I can not do with `hbase` command. I have used following command for it

```
hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv -Dimporttsv.separator="," -Dimporttsv.columns=cf:mobile  test1 hdfs://master.ambari.com:8020/user/root/www/dnd_20170705_0.csv
```

but I am getting following error.

```
ERROR: Must specify exactly one column as HBASE_ROW_KEY
```

Do you have any idea about it or any other way I can push data into hbase table.

Comment: Surely you have to specify what you want to use as a rowKey if you want to store data in HBase, how can it work if you dont?